# Finding JTAG/UART Connections on smart doorbell

Tags: hardware, serial-communication, firmware-analysis, jtag

Trying to dump firmware of this device. I can't find the UART/JTAG connections.
I've searched over it for awhile now; I feel like I must just be missing something.

[image]

[image]